# How do i stop this quicksand animation from glitching?

Tags: html

> http://trulyamped.com/test/art.html

For some weird reason whenever i toggle one of the options such as web/ios/print the animation does a weird glitch and the animation skips.

but when i delete the codes `*, *:after, *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}`

from my style it works properly but only to find that my hover animation is clipped.

So what i am asking is how do i get the animation glitch to stop? (just click on one of the filters on the site to see the glitch)

for comparisons look at http://designwoop.com/labs/filtered-portfolio/ and you can see how smooth it looks

i am really nit picky and the way the animation is not smooth bothers me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's easy since you already know the reason that couses glitch.
quicksand is a plug-in so it's not smart enough to calculate css.
And also it is better not to apply box-sizing css for practice.
I would suggest take the

```
*, *:after, *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

out and calculate width and padding by yourself for figcaption

Comment: yeah i might as well try that thanks, but if anyone finds a workaround let me know